Can't use knex with deno
$ deno run --allow-all npm:knex
Failed to load external module ts-node/register
Failed to load external module typescript-node/register
Failed to load external module typescript-register
Failed to load external module typescript-require
Failed to load external module sucrase/register/ts
Failed to load external module @babel/register
Usage: cli [options] [command]

Options:
  -V, --version                   output the version number
  --debug                         Run with debugging.
  --knexfile [path]               Specify the knexfile path.
  --knexpath [path]               Specify the path to knex instance.
  --cwd [path]                    Specify the working directory.
...

I ran a npm command on my deno project usign the npm: prefix, but it shows me this error. I guess it will be because of lacking npm dependencies but I don't understand what to do next, maybe install knex with npm just for using the commands?
I tried installing each dependency using deno but the result was the same, even installing knex globally didn't make any difference.
